# Using PostCharp to dynamically generate a C# property

Tags: postsharp

I hoping someone can provide some guidance as to how to solve the following challenge. I’ve done a fair amount of research but I’m not able to put all the pieces together. Thank you!

How I’d like to code my POCOs.  Note that there will be many different properties each having a unique `Guid` "backing store" property who's name and `ColumnAttribute` will be a function of the `SomeAspectAttribute` annotation applied to the "main" property (e.g. CreatedBy).

```
[SomeAspectAttribute("_createdby_value")]
public User CreatedBy { get; }
```

I’d like the following to be generated:

```
[JsonIgnore]
[Column("_createdby_value")]
internal Guid _createdby_value { get; set; }

public User CreatedBy { get; set; }
```

So there looks to be a few things going on here. My struggle is putting it all together.

- Add a property. IntroduceMember seems like it would work but I might have many of these where the original property Type and name will vary. Plus, given the need to introduce custom attribute upon this new property, I think I’m gonna need a dynamic, code-based means for creating this property.
- Add custom attribute(s) to the dynamically added property.
- I suspect I’ll need a TypeLevelAspect to find all my properties with the [SomeAspectAttribute] attribute (obviously with a better name) and do some CustomAttributeIntroductionAspect stuff.
- Others?

Comment: Dynamically generating properties would require you to use low-level PostSharp SDK and create a custom weaver, which is not officially supported at the moment. You can try to find some examples online and experiment with them.

Comment: Remember that PostSharp isn't a code generator tool. It is indeed possible to introduce members and interfaces to a class with PostSharp, but these members will not be available to you at compile-time because aspect are applied post-compile. So unless you are using reflection to access these generate properties it will not work.